# Aggregate values by row count

Tags: arrays, aggregate, window-functions, postgresql-9.2

I have a series of rows and I need to aggregate values from these rows into the groups of `N` elements, accumulating values from current and `N-1` succeeding rows.

With `N=3` and data being:

```sql
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5);
```

I want to receive the following set of rows (arrays):

```sql
{1,2,3}
{2,3,4}
{3,4,5}
{4,5}
{5}
```

It is important, that `N` is a variable, so I cannot use joins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this can be solved [using frames together with window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS).

The question in subject can be solved like this:

```sql
WITH v(v) AS (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5))
SELECT v,
       array_agg(v) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND 2 FOLLOWING) AS arr
  FROM v;
```

And the following example illustrates how to get a list of complete arrays, i.e. eliminate those that don't contain all `N` entries:

```sql
WITH cnt(c) AS (SELECT 3),
     val(v) AS (VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5)),
     arr AS
(SELECT v,
        array_agg(v) OVER (ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW
                           AND (SELECT c-1 FROM cnt) FOLLOWING) AS arr
   FROM val)
SELECT v,arr
  FROM arr
 WHERE array_upper(arr,1) = (SELECT c FROM cnt);
```

I really love window functions!